# A return type for a portable memory search function

Tags: c++, pointers, portability

I want to write a portable memory searching function. The signature looks similar to this:

```
return_type FindPattern(uintptr_t start, size_t length, const unsigned char* pattern, const char* mask);
```

The function scans the current process memory starting from the address `start`, for the next `length` bytes and returns the address of the first byte of the first byte sequence matching the given `pattern` with a given `mask`. If the pattern was not found, the function should somehow indicate this, perhaps via a special return value. The main concern is that the null pointer may not be equal to 0 on some platforms.

What return type is the best for this task and how to indicate if the pattern was not found?

Comment: The *physical* representation of the NULL pointer in memory might not be 0. But any standard-conforming operation that returns a null pointer, can be compared to 0 or NULL safely.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Comment: You could return `start + length`

Comment: "Portable memory search" is an oxymoron. Standard C++ only allows you to access defined or allocated objects; accessing outside of those is undefined behavior. This means that writing such a memory search is very much unportable, and you will have to go with some platform-specific assumptions, such as "this specific pointer value is not a valid memory address, I can use it as a failure return code".

Comment: @SebastianRedl But what about standard cstring functions like strstr or memchr? They are basically memory search functions and are supposed to be portable. Although they search for a specific type of object (char) and have a return value of a pointer to that object, so they can return NULL and that gets converted into an appropriate null pointer.

Comment: @IvanMolodetskikh They are portable. It's the caller's responsibility to not give them invalid input.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: It is perfectly acceptable to offload that responsibility to the caller of `FindPattern`. The caller simply has to pass values of `start` and `length` which lie fully within allocated memory (as molbdnilo mentions, the Standard already does the same)

Comment: @MSalters "The function scans current process memory" - that doesn't sound like staying in bounds of anything to me. Sure, the caller can pass valid arguments, but I get the impression that this is about searching large areas of memory for patterns, possibly for manipulating a game or something like that.

Comment: Well, it's still a portable _function_, even if a particular caller has obtained a pair of arguments in some non-portable way. (Assuming that the function carefully stays within that range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, a range is generally represented by a pair of iterators: `[begin, end)` and it is customary that `find`, `search`, `mismatch`, etc... will return `end` to signal the absence of match.

I would therefore advise simply following in those footsteps, since it will instantly make your own function seem familiar to C++ users.

That being said, if you insist on using a null pointer, then using either `0` or `nullptr` (C++11 and above) is portable; the literal `0` is translated to whatever is suitable on the target platform by the compiler.

Comment: If on some platform I can access the whole memory, what type should be `end`? `uintptr_t`, `size_t` and similar would be capable of storing only the highest pointer value, and to search the whole memory I would need to give a value one higher than that.

Comment: The types of both should be `void*`. If you can access the whole memory, it's likely safe to use `last address + 1` as the end value. Yes, that overflows, but overflow is generally safe on the type of systems that you presupposed.

Comment: @IvanMolodetskikh: The question has less to do with how much memory you can access, and whether the segment of memory you can access can be represented using `T*`. Since, as mentioned, the Standard Library uses `T*` exclusively, then the Standard Library itself would be broken on such a platform. Conversely though, by embracing the same idioms, your solution is as portable as the Standard Library itself. Is it not enough?

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume that you didn't mean for the pattern and mask to have different types. Given that, just return a pointer of that type and if not found either the literal `0` or if you have C++11 `nullptr`. The literal zero is guaranteed to be the null pointer *even if the system's null pointer isn't all zero bits*.

Comment: The pattern is a sequence of bytes, for instance, defined like this: `const unsigned char pattern[] = { 0xA1, 0x56, 0x83 };` while a mask is a string consisting of characters that indicate that a byte should be matched, and characters that indicate that a byte should not be matched, as in any byte will pass, for example: `const char mask[] = "x?x";` will requre a strict match of the first and the third byte, and the second byte might have any value.